# MediaWiki: How to create a section for the parent page in a template?

Tags: templates, mediawiki

I use a template to include a special box in some of my sites. After the template code there is some content, that visually belongs to the box created by the temaplte. Now I want to make it easier to edit the content of the resulting box.

My idea was to add an 'edit' link to the top right of the box, that opens the editor with only the content of this box. As headlines automatically create sections, I tried adding one to the template. But this only created an edit link for the template itself.

How can I make the template create a new 'section' in the parent page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The edit link will point to page which has the section code in its wikitext (directly, not included). The usual method is to have the template include some subpage, and point the edit link to that subpage.

### Simple version

Template:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">Stuff in a box ([{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff|action=edit}} edit])</div>
  {{ {{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff }}
</div>
```

When you place this template on page `Foo`, it will include the subpage `Foo/stuff` (third line, see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Page_names) for explanation of `FULLPAGENAME`) and show an edit link to it (second line, see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#URL_data) for `fullurl`).

### Parserfunction-based version

If you have [the ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aParserFunctions) installed, you can use it to detect whether the subpage exists:

```
<div class="box">
{{#ifexist:{{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff
|
  <div class="box-header">Stuff in a box ([{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff|action=edit}} edit])</div>
  {{ {{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff }}
|
  <div class="box-error">No stuff for this page! [{{fullurl:{{FULLPAGENAME}}/stuff|action=edit}} Click here] to create.</div>
}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do... but how do I do that?

Comment: See [this template](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:To_do&oldid=4919890) for an example.

Comment: Thanks Tgr... I went over through that, but I can't tell what's going on... do you have a working example of some sort